# How write code that creates a Dataset with columns that have the elements of an array column as values and their names being positions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input data:

```
    val inputDf = Seq(Seq("a", "b", "c"), Seq("X", "Y", "Z")).toDF
    println("Input:")
    inputDf.show(false)
```

Here is how look Input:

```
    +---------+
    |value    |
    +---------+
    |[a, b, c]|
    |[X, Y, Z]|
    +---------+
```

Here is how look Expected:

```
    +---+---+---+
    |0  |1  |2  |
    +---+---+---+
    |a  |b  |c  |
    |X  |Y  |Z  |
    +---+---+---+
```

I tried use code like this:

```
    val ncols = 3

    val selectCols = (0 until  ncols).map(i => $"arr"(i).as(s"col_$i"))

    inputDf
      .select(selectCols:_*)
      .show()
```

But I have errors, because I need some :Unit

Comment: it is better if you accept the answers from the solvers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

object ArrayToCol extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val inptDf = Seq(Seq("a", "b", "c"), Seq("X", "Y", "Z")).toDF("value")
  val d = inptDf
    .withColumn("0", col("value").getItem(0))
    .withColumn("1", col("value").getItem(1))
    .withColumn("2", col("value").getItem(2))
    .drop("value")

  d.show(false)

}
// Variant 2
val res = inptDf.select(
    $"value".getItem(0).as("col0"),
    $"value".getItem(1).as("col1"),
    $"value".getItem(2).as("col2")
  )
// Variant 3
val res1 = inptDf.select(
    col("*") +: (0 until 3).map(i => col("value").getItem(i).as(s"$i")): _*
  )
    .drop("value")
```

Comment: I tried, but I still have error: Type mismatch, need :Unit

Comment: please, last version my answer - @rabbit

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create a dataframe ---

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,[4,2, 1]),(4,[3,2])], [ "col2","col4"])
```

**OUTPUT---------**

```
+----+---------+
|col2|     col4|
+----+---------+
|   1|[4, 2, 1]|
|   4|   [3, 2]|
+----+---------+
```